# React Native LayoutAnimation scale doesn't work on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, layout-animation

I am using react-native's LayoutAnimation custom component with maps. On ios animation works properly, but not on android. I'm changing component height

```
const HeightAnimation = {
duration: 200,
create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.scaleXY
},
update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following flags via UIManager. Did you do this in your code?

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}
```

You could check the docs here -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation

Comment: Yes, I did, doesn't help

Comment: create an expo snack here => https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: I can't do it due to NDA, any other ideas?

Comment: @Mykyta just copy the code which throws you that error, and make it a snack. You don't need to copy out the whole project.